# In optimization, what does the text beneath 'min' or 'max' specify?

Tags: optimization, notation

In my studies I have come across formulations like the following:

$$\max_{f \in \mathcal{F}} f(x)$$

where $f$ is some function in a family of functions $\mathcal{F}$ and $x$ is some real-valued variable assumed fixed for the sake of this optimization. As far as I understand, $\max$ implies that we try to maximize $f(x)$, but I am uncertain as how to how I should read the text below ($f \in \mathcal{F}$). Does this mean I am maximizing under the assumption that $f \in \mathcal{F}$ (which seems an oddly unrelated piece of information), or does the text below specify what it is I am varying, i.e. that I maximize this by trying different $f$s (from my set $\mathcal{F}$)? Or does it mean something entirely different I haven't yet considered?

I apologize if this is a trivial question for someone with a more rigorous background in math, but I could not find a clear definition elsewhere.

Comment: $\max_{f\in F}f(x) = \max\{f(x) : f\in F\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subscripted part describes how the item to be maximized can vary. So in
$$\max_{f \in \mathcal{F}} f(x)$$
you are looking for the maximum value of $f(x)$ as $f$ varies over the collection $\mathcal F$.

Presumably, $x$ is fixed here, so this would determine a value dependent on $x$. If $\mathcal F$ is a finite collection, one might also write this as
$$\max\{f_1(x), f_2(x),\ldots, f_n(x)\}.$$

Comment: Ah, that clears it up, thank you! $x$ is indeed fixed for this problem. I have clarified this above.

Answer (score 3):

I think the intent is to vary different $f$'s over the family $\mathcal{F}$.

For example, if $\mathcal{F} = \{f_n(x)| n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ with $f_n(x):[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x^n$, then
$$
\max_{f \in \mathcal{F}} f(x) = \max \{f_n(x)| x \in [0,1], n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\} = 1.
$$

The alternative, as suggested by @MPW in the comments below, is that the notation in the question could be interpreted *as a function of $x$*, in other words,
$$
F(x) = \max_{f \in \mathcal{F}} f(x) = \max_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} f_n(x) = x.
$$

Comment: As written, $x$ is free, so the result should be a function of $x$.

Comment: @MPW +1, but it's a bit ambiguous to me. I would agree with you if it was explicit, i.e. something like $$F(x) = \max_{f \in \mathcal{F}} f(x)$$ but this feels like could go either way. Will update the answer with this interpretation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I indeed assumed $x$ fixed here. I have clarified this in the question.

Comment: @J.Galt no problem, I am glad MPW provided his answer and comments to mine.